# Turn list of JSON objects into a single JSON Array

Tags: java, json

I'm using the org.json.simple.JSONObject library to read some text and form it into JSON.

The code I have is as follows:

```html
public class PerfMetrics {

   private static String filePath = "Shell_Pricing_Metrics.json";
   private static String jsoncontent;

public static void clearFileContents(String filePath) throws IOException {
    File f1 = new File(filePath);
    new FileWriter(f1);
}

public static void metricAsJSON(String testName, long testTime) {

    Date date = new Date();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("testname", testName);
    obj.put("Duration", testTime);
    obj.put("Timestamp", ts.toString());

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(obj.toJSONString());
    jsoncontent = gson.toJson(je);

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    jsonArray.add(je);

    jsoncontent = gson.toJson(jsonArray);
    
}

public static void writeJsonToFile() {

        try {

            File f1 = new File(filePath);

            if (!(f1.exists())) {
                f1.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(f1, true);

            PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(fw1);
            if (f1.exists() && f1.isFile()) {
                pw1.println(jsoncontent);
                pw1.flush();
                pw1.close();
                fw1.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please provide a valid path to destination Json file");
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Writes to a file as:

```
[
   {
    "Duration": 30,
    "testname": "Upload Data click to Model Prices dropdown display time:",
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-15 09:47:53.804"
  }
]
```

I need the data as:

```
[
   {
    "testname": "Shopping dropdown display time:",
    "Duration": 2156,
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-10 14:29:01.945"
  },
  {
    "testname": "Clothing dropdown display time:",
    "Duration": 3567,
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-10 14:30:01.534"
  },
  {
    "testname": "Electrical dropdown display time:",
    "Duration": 2098,
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-10 14:33:01.532"
  },
  {
    "testname": "Toys dropdown display time:",
    "Duration": 4562,
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-10 14:35:01.435"
  }
]
```

I can get around this clunkily with my limited Java skills but wondered what is the best library / practice to support the transformation of the object strings into a Json Array?

Comment: use Gson or Jackson libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the function once per `JSONObject`, and writing the file each time - if that's the case then you could instead return the `JSONObject` from that method:

```
/*... obj.put(key, value); obj.put('Timestamp') ... */
return obj;
```

And then where you call `.metricAsJSON` now, append it to a `JSONArray` object like so:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
for (... metric in some other array ...) {
  JSONObject obj = GetMetrics.metricAsJSON(key, value);
  arr.put(obj);
}
String jsonString = arr.toString();
/* Write jsonString to file */
```

If you need to add values dynamically and write multiple times, you could store the `JSONArray` as a method variable, or load the file into a `JSONArray` object each time you need to append something to the end.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've amended the code.  The get metricAsJSON methode does indeed get called once every time I collect a JsonObject string.  I now just need to concatenate / append each object onto the existing array.  I'm now writing to the file at the very end.  Should be straightforward from here I think!  Perhaps this is a different question

Comment: I can't remember off hand but you should be able to load the .JSON file into a JSONArray directly, which should give you the tools to append. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
public class GetMetrics {

public static void clearFileContents(String filePath) throws IOException {
File f1 = new File(filePath);
new FileWriter(f1);
}

public static void metricAsJSON(String key, long value, String filePath) {

Date date = new Date();
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put(key, value);
obj.put("Timestamp", ts.toString());

try {
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
 JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
 JsonElement je = jp.parse(obj.toJSONString());
 String jsoncontent = = gson.toJson(je);

 File f1 = new File(filePath);

 if (!(f1.exists())) {
  f1.createNewFile();
 }

 FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(f1, true);

 PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(fw1);
 if (f1.exists() && f1.isFile()) {
  pw1.println(jsoncontent);
  pw1.flush();
  pw1.close();
  fw1.close();
 } else {
  System.out.println("Please provide a valid path to destination Jsonfile");
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you - this prettifies the data, but does not add commas to separate the objects nor the square brackets to open and close the array